# Adding multiple images for share button og:image tags

Tags: html, facebook

I try to do include multiple og:image meta properties to associate multiple images with my page. According to Facebook's Open Graph protocol documentation, you have only put multiple og:image tags in the html head.

That's what I did but unfortunately it doesn't work. I would be pleased, if anyone could give me a hint.

I have been using the debug page and Facebooks seems to parse it just fine because I see my metatag images:

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="United Serbian Soccer Club" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="United Serbian Soccer Club" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com/images/USSC_futsal_tournament_2016.png" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com/images/anualindoortournament2016/FKCZ_MKE_open_winner.jpg" />
```

Even see the images in the og:image Open Graph properties section, however it always takes only first image and ignores others.

Here is currently my main HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>United Serbians</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/USSC_logo_icon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coin-slider.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/main_bg.jpg);
}
a:link {
    color: #DF0000;
}
</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/droid_sans_400-droid_sans_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="20312314" />
<meta property="og:title" content="United Serbian Soccer Club" />
<meta property="og:description" content="United Serbian Soccer Club" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com/images/USSC_futsal_tournament_2016.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.unitedserbians.com/images/anualindoortournament2016/FKCZ_MKE_open_winner.jpg" />
</head>
```

You can see an example page here:

http://www.unitedserbians.com/

Comment: Facebook doesn’t offer the user a choice between multiple OG images any more when sharing a link. This feature is now at most useful to specify images in different dimensions, so Facebook can pick one that seems most appropriate when the post is displayed in different situations.

Comment: That's it. Check the dimensions of the images, following the open gaph standards. So you can specificate one square image and also an horizontal image, for feeds and also for sharer. Feed ui dialog, for example use squared picture, exactly as commented above .. You can try to implement feed dialog so you can display dialogs for sharing, use js sdk. So you can specify the image that will be shared :)